# Best way to temporarily store data before it is saved into a database in a Node.js webapp?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies

I'm new to Node.js and I'm working on a simple web app with Node.js and MongoDB. I created an API that can save and retrieve data to and from the database. However, I want to minimize these database operations.

What would be the best way to store data *temporarily* before it is saved in the database?

The use case is as follows:

1. An unregistered user goes to a webpage.
2. The user fills out forms that are on page1, page2, page3 and so on.
3. First now, the user registers and the data should be saved into the database.

Step 3 is working, but I am not sure where to store the data from step 1 and 2. Should I use cookies or sessions or is there maybe another way?

Thanks for a reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could suggest you to use in-memory DBs to do such things if you really want to keep temporary data with you. Redis with Node.js is best for caching information for short term periods rather than long term solutions like PostgreSQL, MySQL and so many. Redis, which stands for Remote Dictionary Server, is a fast, open-source, in-memory key-value data store for use as a database, cache, message broker, and queue.

You can check [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-redis-node-js/) for how to use it.

There could be other ways too, but at this moment I think you can go with this.

Comment: Thanks! Using Redis is a great idea I did not think of.